# Do you need to fclose() both files after freopen()?

Tags: c, fopen, freopen

I'm writing a code which takes one file and saves it into another with a different name - however, I am not sure whether or not I need to fclose both files or not?

```
FILE *logfile = fopen("log.txt", "a+");
while(1) {
    char filename[500];
    char logline[512]; 
    char channel[512];

    //Do stuff

    sprintf(filename, "%s.log.txt", channel);
    freopen(filename, "a+", logfile);
    log_to_file(logline, logfile);
}
```

Comment: When the program ends both files will be automatically closed, so it is not extrictly necessary, but yes recommendable

Comment: You can have multiple files opened at the same time, just make sure you close them at some point.(if some other program tries to access the files you are reading/writing problems might arise) If you are %100 sure no one else uses these files, do whatever you want.

Comment: `freopen` closes the original file, and associates the given `FILE` pointer with the new file. Which means that the code only has one file open at a time, and therefore only one file to close. And yes, it is good practice to close a file when you're done with it.

Comment: @user3386109 Perfect! That's exactly what I couldn't confirm - I wasn't sure if the old pointer still needed to be closed or not. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/freopen)

> The `freopen()` function opens the file whose name is the string pointed to by path and associates the stream pointed to by stream with it. **The original stream (if it exists) is closed.** [...]

So, you don't need to close the previous stream explicitly, once done usage, just close the recent stream.